# SCORM - set in read only mode

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

We have implemented simple LMS based on Basic Web Player which is part of SharePoint Learning Kit. Now we are looking for way to be able to set SCORM in read only, eg for teacher review or parent.

Is there any SCORM data model option or options which can be set to disable it's content for editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You don't simply develop a SCORM API

I have been in the process of developing a LMS-RTE and a SCO for roughly a year of constant refinements and extensions. The quintessential truth I have learned is that almost everybody does a terrible job.

The SCORM standard is, at best, a little loose... Any feature present in the SCO <-> RTE interactions must be mirrored on both sides. If the LMS-Vendor ads a review feature every SCO has to implement it too. There is no way to force behavior on the SCO from the LMS side, since too many fields are optional. Even worse there is no way to automatically inspect a SCO and determine if a certain field was used and the SCO behaved as expected.

So theoretically cmi.mode preset to review should do the trick, but almost every content vendor I have encountered ignores this setting. I think everything you can get out of here is the answer: Yes it's possible, but only if the SCO supports this feature.

I personally found found logging of SCO <-> RTE communication the best solution to determine wich behavior the SCO could possibly be capable of. If you log all get and all set requests to different logs and log wich properties are touched by the SCO, you will get a idea of what the SCO can do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use cmi.mode data model element. Could you explain more, please?